# How can I create a 46 GB RAM image on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks

I am looking to deploy an application on AKS that is very demandind in RAM.
I need kubernetes to go up to 46 GB of RAM.

But for now I still can't figure out how to request that many RAM.

I did found how to do it on docker but kubernetes still eludes me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Can you explain more clearly about what is it that you are trying to achieve? And what do you exaclty mean by "ram image" ?

Comment: Your question is too common. Please reask your question with more details of your setup. Closing this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For containers and pods, in the container's resource manifest in kubernetes you would specify a memory request for 46GB, for example,

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
      requests:
        memory: "100Mi"
```

More information at the following webpage,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/

After having a look into the defaults, if no limits have been set, on the container or on the namespace, then there is no limit set.

Comment: Thank a lot for your response, I am very new on this subject. It's a real pleasure to have some help =)